# C++ code runs with missing header, why?

Tags: c++, header, std

I just realized that I am supposed to include the `#include<cstdlib>` required by `abs()` for the `abs()` function.

```
 #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {
        int result;
        result = abs(-10);
        cout << result << "\n";
        return 0;

    }
```

**Why does this code still work, even though I forgot the important header (`#include<cstdlib>`)?**

Comment: what's your platform, compiler?

Comment: Win7Prof Visual C++ 2008 Express Edition

Comment: I guess this depends on compiler too .. btw:nice question +1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's because `iostream` indirectly includes definition for `abs()`. It is allowed by the Standard, but should not be relied upon, because it's implementation-dependant (i.e. your code may not compile on some other compilers).

Comment: In other words, just include #include<cstdlib> to avoid problems in the future, thanks atzz.